# Installing findbugs on Ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu, hadoop, findbugs

For the purpose of building hadoop, I need to install findbugs. I tried to install it by following the [link](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/universe/f/findbugs/install/index.html). I see that findbugs had installed properly. But when I run the maven build command for hadoop I still see the same error at hadoop-common:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (site) on project hadoop-common: An Ant BuildException has occured: input file /home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/findbugsXml.xml does not exist
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<xslt in="/home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/findbugsXml.xml" style="${env.FINDBUGS_HOME}/src/xsl/default.xsl" out="/home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/site/findbugs.html"/>... @ 44:277 in /home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

I am stuck at this point. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`"input file /home/raghuveer/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/findbugsXml.xml does not exist"`*

A resource file usually should reside in `<your project>/src/main/resources/` to be copied to `/target` during the build.

See [Maven, Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and [Apache Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/):

> *The Resources Plugin handles the copying of project resources to the output directory.*

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could tell me where can i find this xml or how to create it.

Comment: @Raghuveer See [FindBugs Maven Plugin, Usage, Generate FindBugs xdoc Report As Part of the Project Reports](https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html#Generate_FindBugs_xdoc_Report_As_Part_of_the_Project_Reports): _"The output file will be written as `findbugs.xml` to ..."_